# IDispatchMessageInspector and InstanceContextMode.Single order not maintained

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have a single instance, single threaded WCF service (a requirement). I need to perform one function e.g `ClearUnmanagedState()` before every operation contract executes. I have implemented `IDispatchMessageInspector` and `AfterReceiveRequest` for this but have found this executes on message receive, not when the operation is about to be executed.

Therefore, my `InstanceContextMode.Single` is not being respected in respect to this `ClearUnmanagedState()` requirement.

Is there any WCF service behavior that I can implement to allow a single context, single threaded execution before operation contract execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an [IOperationInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ioperationinvoker.aspx).

One of the best example implementations is Carlos Figueira's blog:
[WCF Extensibility – IOperationInvoker](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/17/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker.aspx)

> The operation invoker is the last element in the WCF runtime which is
>   invoked before the user code (service implementation) is reached –
>   it’s the invoker responsibility to actually call the service operation
>   on behalf of the runtime.